# Python :unbound method receive() must be called with MessageNet instance as first argument (got MessageGlobal instance instead)

Tags: python, django

I have an issue here is my django view

```
 def home(request):
        try:
            from_number  = request.GET['from_number']
            to_number  = request.GET['to_number']
            messagetext  = request.GET['msg_text']
            date_time  = request.GET['date_time']
            date_received  = request.GET['date_received']
            status = 0
        except:
            LOG_ERROR('Invalid Parameter')

            #Return to some product page or 500 error with message
            #pass    #  return some value  after discussing with sir 
     #      #Based on from number identify the Vmn and his class anc class the respective receieve method of that class
        if from_number !=None  and to_number != None:
            try:getvmn = ServiceProvider.objects.get(status = False)
            except:
                LOG_FATAL("VMN doesn't exists ")
                getvmn = False
            if getvmn:
                print "-=-=-=-=-==-=-=-==================="
    #           get_related_class = ServiceProvider.objects.filter(id  = getvmn.merchant,status = False)
                get_related_class = ServiceProvider.objects.get(status = False)
                b = SMSMgr()
                for objec in b._allsp:
                    if objec.class_Name == 'MessageNet':
                       # messageglobalobject  =     
                        MessageNet.receive(MessageGlobal(from_number,to_number,messagetext,date_received,status))
```

Here is smsmessage.py

```
class MessageGlobal():
    def __init__(self,from_number,to_number,messagetext,date,status = None):
        self.messagetext = messagetext
        self.to_number = to_number
        self.from_number = from_number
        self.date = date
        self.status = status
```

Here is MessageNet class

```
class MessageNet():
    def __init__(self,username,password,sendingurl,class_Name):
        self.username = username
        self.password = password
        self.messagetext = None
        self.sendingurl = sendingurl
        self.class_Name = class_Name
        self.PhoneNumber = None
       # self.apiurl = apiurl

    def send(self,mg):

        payload = {'username': self.username, 'Pwd': self.password,'PhoneNumber':mg.tonumber,'PhoneMessage':mg.messagetext}
        r = requests.get(self.sendingurl, params=payload)
        LOG_INFO("Message sent to %s  via  %s", self.PhoneNumber,'Messagenet')
        #   Call to ms manager 

    def receive(self,getmessageobject):

        print "receive and notify the user "
```

I am getting the error in line

```
MessageNet.receive(MessageGlobal(from_number,to_number,messagetext,date_received,status))
of my views .
```

I am trying to pass a object of MessageGlobal to the receieve method so that i can access them inside receive method of MessageNet class  .

Please tell me Why ai am getting this error .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're calling an instance method on a class rather than an instance. You need to instantiate a `MessageNet` object, then call `receive` on that instance, not on the class.

Alternatively you could make it a classmethod, but then you won't have access to any of the instance attributes (password, etc).

Answer (score 0):

You're getting it because you're passing a `MessageGlobal` instance to a method on `MessageNet`. Either pass a `MessageNet` instance instead, or turn the method into a normal function.

Comment: Not really sure how you want me to elaborate. That's already the whole problem.